Water pipes through a plasterboard
I have a small WC where I'd like to install a washbasin. In the floor plan below, the green rectangle is where the basin would be, and the other colors are existing water sources and pipes. The thin walls are plasterboard (about 7cm thick, composed of 2 sheets of 1cm-thick cardboard-like material with 5cm of empty space between them).

I need to find out how to bring water (at least cold, ideally hot as well) and how to connect the drainage pipe to the washbasin.
Given that just behind the wall there is a kitchen sink, with all the required pipes, the simplest solution to me seems to be:

Drill 3 holes in the plasterboard;
Add a tee to the existing hold and cold water pipes;
Connect the washbasin drainage to the existing kitchen drainage.

However, when I called a handyman to do it, he said he really dislikes drilling holes like this, and would much prefer getting the cold water from the toilet inlet, and then drilling a hole in the existing toilet drainage. It would look like this:

The washbasin is to the right, the blue line represents the pipe coming from the toilet, and the orange line the future drainage from the washbasin to the existing toilet drainage. No holes necessary, other than a circular hole in this pipe:

For information, this is what the cold water source looks like (it's a plastic pipe coming from the floor):

My solution would be to start from the kitchen and drill these holes:

The wall just behind this photo is exactly where the washbasin would be installed.
It seems I'd need this kind of bulkhead connector to connect pipes in both sides:

But I'm not sure if it's too heavy for the plasterboard, or if I'd need some other kind of support.
So what I'm wondering is: is the handyman right in preferring not to drill the holes? Is there a major problem concerning pipes that pass through plasterboard?

What's your location?  My guess is outside the US.

Yes, this is in Europe. Is there some specific US law that forbids this?

Not that I'm aware of, but I'm not an expert.  It's just more the thin walls that are very unlike the US.

Find a better handyman. Or an actual plumber. Your original idea is valid; one does need to be careful about what might be in the wall you are drilling through, but this level of avoiding it does not speak to the person being competent. The walls actually sound pretty typical if we overlook the plasterboard being described as cardboard - 1/2" sheetrock over a nominal 2x3" frame (non-structural wall) comes out about that size

@Huesmann builders are greedy beasts, and every inch (or centimeter, since it's EU) they can get means more square meters or "livable surface", and therefore they can charge more. So they make walls as thin as physically (and legally) possible. Which also means very poor soundproofing.

No, I get it.  It's just flimsy walls.

You don't need that sort of connector through the wall. Normal practice (why I question your alleged "handyman's" competence in a comment) is to simply pass the pipes through the wall and (if exposed to view) use "escutcheons" (trim plates; since there are other types, for keyholes etc, specifically ones for pipes) around the pipes to conceal the rough edges of the hole, or the drywall compound (or plaster) used to fill in around the hole which can be difficult to get perfectly smooth. They also save having to find matching paint there.

Image Source, no affiliation.
When drilling through the wall, the experienced worker drills only through the first sheet of plasterboard and stops to have a look for any obstacles before drilling further. If resistance is encountered when drilling the first hole, stopping and relocating the hole, or drilling a small hole and using a borescope camera to take a look may be a better plan than drilling right through a hidden obstruction, which might be a pipe or cable.

Thank you for the indication about the escutcheons. I'm only worried about physical support: are the holes also supposed to physically hold the pipes in place (especially drainage), or is this supposed to be handled by the "vertical" parts of the pipes, which are attached to the plasterboard via clamps/brackets? In other words: are the scutcheons themselves attached to the plasterboard, and thus support the pipes, or do the pipes support themselves and also the scutcheons, which are thus "loose"? The incoming water pipes are PEX and not copper.

The hole is not supporting the pipe to any great extent; nor are the escutcheons. Plenty of pipes have a gaping hole around them if you pull the escutcheon back. However, filling in around the pipe does tend to limit issues with other things using that opening as a passageway, and may provide some trivial level of support. I general, if the pipe needs support (long or heavy) it should be attached to framing with suitable hardware.
